# Vector autoregressive models in R

Tags: r, references, vector-autoregression

Can anyone recommend a good tutorial/blog/books which introduces the theory behind vector auto-regressive models but also shows some example code snippets in R?

Comment: See https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/2

Comment: See the vignette of the "vars" package in R by Pfaff: ["VAR, SVAR and SVEC Models: Implementation Within R Package vars"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf).

Comment: Hmm, how should I have formulated the answer so that it would have not been converted into a comment? I have provided a reference as asked by the OP. The answer was short, but it contained all that is needed, IMHO.

Comment: @Richard Including some comments explaining why you are making this recommendation or describing its contents would have spared your post, I believe.  It looks like a useful answer.